# Feature extraction for butterfly images

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, image-segmentation

I have a set of butterfly images for training my system to segment a butterfly from a given input image. For this purpose, I want to extract the features such as edges, corners, region boundaries, local maximum/minimum intensity etc.

I found many feature extraction methods like Harris corner detection, SIFT but they didn't work well when the image background had the same color as that of the butterfly's body/boundary color.

Could anyone please tell whether there is any good feature extraction method which works well for butterfly segmentation? I'm using the Python implementation of OpenCV.

Comment: sample images would help a lot

Comment: Hi @Hammer, i used the dataset from Leeds' (http://goo.gl/YYRcn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you willing to write your own image processing logic?

Your best option will likely be to optimize the segmentation/feature extraction for your problem, instead of using previous implementations like opencv meant for more general use-cases.

An option that I've found to work well in noisy/low-contrast environments is to use a sliding window (i.e. 10x10 pixels) and build a gradient orientation histogram. From this histogram you can recognize the presence of more dominant edges (they accumulate in the histogram) and their orientations (allowing for detection for things like corners) and see the local maximum/minimums. (I can give more details if needed)

If your interested in segmentation as a whole AND user interaction is possible, I would recommend graph cut or grab cut. In graph cut users would be able to fine tune the segmentation. Grab cut is already in opencv, but may result in the same problems as it takes a single input from the user, then automatically segments the image.

Comment: Hi @Noremac, I'm interested in segmenting the butterfly as a whole and for initial testing, I'd like to draw a bounding box around a butterfly to see whether my segmentation is working or not. One implicit issue which I'm facing is when the butterfly is occluded.
Also I'd like to know more about the gradient histogram method that you've mentioned.

Writing my own logic would be great but for a kick-start, I'm trying to implement already existing methods for segmentation.

Comment: The reference I used for this is in the free pdf book at: http://szeliski.org/Book/. This is a great reference book and directs you where to go for more detail. The pages 218,219 was what got me started on using them. They are a part of SIFT features, but only the dominant gradient is kept, whereas I used more features than that (eventually to a neural network for classification). You may find more ideas for features to use in this section as well.

Comment: Thanks @Noremac, Will go through this book!

Comment: Hi @Noremac, I just ran the grabCut method available in Python and got the following outputs (masks) as shown in these links
http://i.imgbox.com/adeIIA1r.jpg
http://i.imgbox.com/acbMc39O.png
http://i.imgbox.com/adciD5hx.jpg
http://i.imgbox.com/adw9yReC.png
Can you tell me how I can use this mask to extract the "colored-butterfly" from the picture?
By the way, I referred to the code mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469244/opencv-python-bindings-for-grabcut-algorithm

Comment: To apply a mask to an image simply iterate through the pixels, set those in the mask as white (or some other color) and those not in the mask as the original pixel. The coordinates of the map should (need) to match up between the two. I'm thinking opencv has a function to apply a mask as well. Either way, it's a simple block of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try building a model by uploading your training data (images of butterlys) to [demo.nanonets.ai](http://demo.nanonets.ai/ImageCategorization/?utm_source=so&utm_content=41120092&utm_medium=so) (free to use)

1) Upload your training data here:

[demo.nanonets.ai](http://demo.nanonets.ai/ImageCategorization/?utm_source=so&utm_content=41120092&utm_medium=so)

2) Then query the API using the following (Python Code):

```
import requests
import json
import urllib
model_name = "Enter-Your-Model-Name-Here"
url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xT6UsQwZyy0/maxresdefault.jpg"
files = {'uploadfile': urllib.urlopen(url).read()}
url = "http://demo.nanonets.ai/classify/?appId="+model_name
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print json.loads(r.content)
```

3) the response looks like:

```
{
  "message": "Model trained",
  "result": [
    {
      "label": "Black Swallowtail",
      "probability": 0.97
    },
    {
      "label": "Orange Sulphur",
      "probability": 0.025
    },
    {
      "label": "Monarch",
      "probability": 0.005
    }
  ]
}
```